# Cut Floor joists for HVAC

Tags: joists, ducts, structural

[image][image]I own an old home, circa 1919. In the 70's, when the new furnace was installed, they cut through the floor joists to run the air ducts. Awesome. So in direct correlation to those cut joists, are outside cracks in the stucco.

So....Where do I even start? Can I reroute the ducts just a little bit? It's not a living-type basement. I don't care about the ceiling/headroom. Then I can fix the floor joists?

Sigh. Please advise. Anything would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding some pictures would help us to see what you can do, especially if you can show how much the floor joists were cut

Comment: How old is the stucco ?

Comment: Stucco is original, but where the cracks are, someone slapped a patch on, over the paint circa 1970's. (They didn't do it right.) I've resigned myself to the fact that i have to pull that back and replace it there.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, that wasn't very smart of them. Fixing the stucco is likely a bandage for the issue they created here.

You'll have to move the vents and then sister a beam on both sides of the cut. First, get two construction jacks to raise the beams back to level. Next, sistering involves buying some new boards that are the same size as the cut ones. Then you construction adhesive the new boards and pass bolts through all 4 boards to hold them together. You'll probably want to fill the void the duct work left as well.

It's worth consulting with a structural engineer to ensure nothing else is wrong.

Comment: Fun fact...That vent comes up directly under where my fridge is....and it's the only place a fridge can go in that kitchen, so there's always been a fridge over the vent...

Comment: @KateSchmidt Wow. Double fail in remodeling. But at least you can fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they cut the main house beam. Not the joist, the duct goes in the joist bay,and they took out some bridging . Get two adjustable lally jacks. Place on both sides of notch. Jack up slowly,and take your time. Do not do all a once if real bad. If you go to fast more plaster or even framing members could snap. Once jacks are in you are fine,and bring up over a month,or less. Go down tighten up jack every other day let it settle, and do it some more. To the point it is where you want it. Then add your wood and new post if needed. A house this old you will use the jacks over and over. I can see the sag in the picture. Your beam may need post, every 8 or 10 feet. the jacks will help ,get four if you need to. good tool.

Comment: He has a small orbit. Yes get the  adjustable lally jacks only 30 bucks  at  HD or Lowes..If you ask for adjustable lally columns. they are a permanent type  around  70 to 125  dollars ,witch you could use if  you need permanent support. or the are also called adjustable steel columns

Comment: It is lally not lalley  so do not show list.